# Purple screen after logo and before login (20.04) - maybe due to AMD

Tags: drivers, 20.04, amd-graphics, gigabyte

I have a Gigabyte H87-HD3 desktop with AMD Radeon HD 7850. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 (completely erasing Windows 7) a few days ago and I still can't get it to start without "nomodeset", because of purple screen before login (I see the Ubuntu logo for 1-2sec and then plain purple, no logos, no errors)

Esc and Crt+Alt+Del: nothing happens. Ctr+Alt+F4: Terminal starts and asks for login and password. I provide them and it seems that Ubuntu runs normally, but without any GUI, only Terminal.

I searched extensively for a solution and I tried installing mesa ppa and oibaf ppa for drivers, but it still didn't work, although I made sure everything is installed, updated and upgraded. I also tried to modify the GRUB, adding "radeon.modeset=0" (and (...)=1) after "quiet splash" and still purple screen. I also tried installing proprietary drivers only to find they are discontinued. This is the info I think may help:

```
biller25@Biller:~$ sudo lshw -c video 
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Pitcairn PRO [Radeon HD 7850 / R7 265 / R9 270 1024SP]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d003ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0400000-d07fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

and

```
biller25@Biller:~$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics driver: N/A 
           Device-2: AMD Pitcairn PRO [Radeon HD 7850 / R7 265 / R9 270 1024SP] driver: N/A 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: ati,fbdev unloaded: modesetting,radeon,vesa 
           resolution: 1024x768~76Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.0 256 bits) 
           v: 4.5 Mesa 22.0.0-devel (git-c4d9041 2021-11-06 focal-oibaf-ppa)
```

I don't really understand it and there is also a great chance I messed up a lot of things in my attempt to fix the purple screen. I hope someone can help.

Edit: This is the neofetch result, after the reinstallation of gdm* and gnome*

```
biller25@Biller:~$ neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               biller25@Biller 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           --------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: H87-HD3 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.11.0-38-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 2 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 1756 (dpkg), 8 (brew), 12  
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.0.17 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1024x768 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel i7-4770 (8) @ 3.900GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: AMD ATI Radeon HD 7850 / R7 265 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         GPU: Intel HD Graphics 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           Memory: 1594MiB / 7837MiB 
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

Comment: Can you Please run `sudo apt install --reinstall gdm* gnome*`

Comment: Also please [edit] the question and add the result of `sudo apt install neofetch ; neofetch`

Comment: I ran the above command and rebooted. It's still not fixed, but it returned this error:

E: Failed to fetch http://(country code).archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/m4/m4_1.4.18-4_amd64.deb  Undetermined Error [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with –fix-missing?